# Radio wave speed in air

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, applied-physics

Couldn't Google credible answer.

What is accepted constant in applied physics to estimate radio wave speed in earth atmosphere near water surface?

Taking on account humidity inside few meters off water surface.

Disregarding ionisation clouds and all other high altitude effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure I was looking for is about 0.9997c

- according to [https://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave.html](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Etsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave.html) *

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer because it will depend on the humidity of the air *and* the frequency. From the humidity you get the fractional water vapor content and *average permittivity*; having the RF frequency and the dispersion relationship for water $\varepsilon_w=\varepsilon_w(\omega)$ weighted by the relative vapor content will give you $\langle\varepsilon\rangle$ and the refractive index $n(\omega)=\sqrt{\langle\varepsilon\rangle}$ and finally the speed $v=c/n$

Comment: Thank you. But if you look at it - its never precise. It is as precise as the amount of effort one is willing to invest in it. You can go as far as modelling it on quantum level and it won't be absolute truth. There must be a practical figure with 2-4 digits precision. I hope there is. 0.99c?

Comment: for details see https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/p/R-REC-P.453-14-201908-I!!PDF-E.pdf